# Twitter API get tweets in particular time range

Tags: twitter, erlang

I'm trying to get the number of tweets in a particular time range for a user, from what I can ascertain you cant do this directly with the REST API.

My boss suggested something about people following our app to be able to get the tweets, is any of this possible? I cant seem to find the answer or will I need to get all the tweets and sort through the JSON according to when the tweet was created?

Bear in mind I'm working in Erlang.

Comment: Are you looking for specific tweets or all of them?

Comment: Well I have a list of user names that I need to check, for each user I need to find the total tweets that have been posted in a time range that is input.

Comment: Fetch the tweets in batches (200 tweets per request) using the `since_id` (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) and then filter upon your stored results.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try